# Interestinting situation. DataBase Error? Python. Django

Tags: python, django

In test server it is working. But production gives this traceback:
what different? And what does that error mean?

Different is only in python versions. In test server it is 2.6.5 and production 2.5.2. How can I get rid of this error with out changing version?

```
True
2008-10-16 15:20:00
 - did not match our database
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mr/local/cluster/dynamic/virtualenv/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 195, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/cluster/dynamic/virtualenv/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 222, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/cluster/dynamic/website/video/remmedia/management/commands/remmedia.py", line 50, in handle
    self.FirstTimeLoad()
  File "/usr/local/cluster/dynamic/website/video/remmedia/management/commands/remmedia.py", line 117, in FirstTimeLoad
    med,created=RemMedia.objects.get_or_create(index=program.Id+50000000, defaults=fields)
  File "/usr/local/cluster/dynamic/virtualenv/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 123, in get_or_create
    return self.get_query_set().get_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/cluster/dynamic/virtualenv/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 335, in get_or_create
    obj.save(force_insert=True)
  File "/usr/local/cluster/dynamic/virtualenv/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 410, in save
    self.save_base(force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/usr/local/cluster/dynamic/virtualenv/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 495, in save_base
    result = manager._insert(values, return_id=update_pk)
  File "/usr/local/cluster/dynamic/virtualenv/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 177, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, values, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/cluster/dynamic/virtualenv/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1087, in insert_query
    return query.execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/cluster/dynamic/virtualenv/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py", line 320, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(InsertQuery, self).execute_sql(None)
  File "/usr/local/cluster/dynamic/virtualenv/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 2369, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/cluster/dynamic/virtualenv/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 84, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/cluster/dynamic/virtualenv/lib/python2.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 158, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
  File "/usr/local/cluster/dynamic/virtualenv/lib/python2.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 265, in literal
    return self.escape(o, self.encoders)
  File "/usr/local/cluster/dynamic/virtualenv/lib/python2.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 198, in string_literal
    return db.string_literal(obj)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

After some time thinking and testing. I notice that error shows only when i do this:

```
med,created=RemMedia.objects.get_or_create(index=program.Id+50000000, defaults=fields)
```

After some more time of thinking end testing, i found the error. It is in dictionary `fields`. There is one variable which i get from BeautifulSoup the code looks like:

```
                        soup=BeautifulSoup(program.Description.encode('utf-8'))
                        name=soup.find('div',{'class':'head'})
                        fields=dict(
                               name=name.string,
                               description=program.Description.encode('utf-8'),
                               program_name=program.Name.encode('utf-8'),
                               program_date_time=program.RealDateTime,
                               topic_data_time=program.RealDateTime,
                               topic_tag='',
                               created=program.Updated,
                               media=media
                                     )
```

The problem is with variable `name` in `fields` dictionary.

Question remain : How to convert it so it will not gives an error?

Comment: What database system are you using in production (looks like MySQL)? What database system are you using in your test environment? Are the two database set-ups in *any way* different?

Comment: They are totally the same! Looks like impossible.

Comment: The different is python version! In firs server it is 2.6.5 and 2.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-10: ordinal not in range(128)`

Do you have a character with an ascii value > 128? Probably an accented letter.

http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

If the problem lies within the database, it's probably a setting. If it's within the python code, you may try placing this line at the top of your python file that deals with the string.

```
# coding:utf-8
```